# Audio streaming stops after 5 seconds

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I'm doing the following in my onCreate() method:

```
mSound = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
soundID = mSound.load(this, R.raw.sample, 1);
streamVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

Then I want the sound file to play by pressing a button... so in my onClick() method I have:

```
mSound.play(soundID, streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 0, 1f);
```

It works great... but only for 5 seconds then it just cuts off... any ideas? Thanks. I'm testing on DROID 3 if that helps.

Comment: why are you getting streamVolume from AudioManager? the way you're using it hear is king of pointless. instead, just pass in 1.0f for right\left volume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SoundPool is created for short audio filesm for example notification files... To play long audio files just use - ...

```
       private MediaPlayer mp_file;  

          ...........
       mp_file = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.big); 
       mp_file.start();
```

Comment: so apparently SoundPool is for files less than 1 MB, my file is almost 4 MB.... bingo. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that R.raw.sample is, in fact, longer than 5 seconds?

If so, by how much? Because note that SoundPool is intended for use with short length samples. If you can't get SoundPool to work, try [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) instead. It's simpler to use and is designed for use with longer samples.